# Initializing and using a gradle.properties file

Tags: powershell, jenkins, gradle, automation, parameter-passing

I am trying pass a parameter from Jenkins into the gradle.properties file to be used for a powershell script. However, I cannot get any parameters from Jenkins to go into the gradle.properties file. I have even created a gradle.properties file and specified the parameter and the powershell script cannot use it.

Here's my Powershell:

```
$ExeFile = $args[0]
write-host $ExeFile
cd 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\AppInstall'
"starting install at $(Get-Date -format 'U')"
($ConsoleCommand = Get-Content -Path .\input.txt -Raw)

# Results - showing the commands in the file before process them
write-host "before foreach loop"
whoami
ForEach($CmdLine in $ConsoleCommand)
{ Start-Process -FilePath $ExeFile -ArgumentList "-NoExit","-Command  &{ $CmdLine }" }
```

Here's my gradle.properties file:

```
 # Enable Gradle daemon for all builds.
 org.gradle.daemon=true

 ExeFile=$ExeFile
```

Here's my gradle.build file:

```
ext.systemProperties= System.properties
String inputFromJenkins = System.getenv('ExeFile')
println('ExeFile = ' + inputFromJenkins)


task execPs(type:Exec) {
   commandLine 'cmd', '/c', 'Powershell -File  appInstall.ps1 '
}
```

Here's the setup in Jenkins:

[jenkins Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECPGl.png)

[folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Suk4h.png)

I appreciate any help, thanks

Comment: Do you want to write a key:value in gradle.properties because your Powershell scripts reads gradle.properties ?

Comment: Yes, that's my intention. I would like to populate the gradle.properties file from Jenkins and pass in the parameters to the powershell script

Comment: Programmatically is possible.  Do you need to read a gradle.properties and **append** new values or just create a new one with jenkins parameters?

Comment: Also, Can you send parameters to your powershell script? If it is possible, write new values to gradle.properties would no longer be necessary.

Comment: I ended up going programmatically by adding a variable ($path=Get-ChildItem -Path ./temp -Recurse -Filter "*.exe") referring to the executable and adding it to the script.